# Dialog on Onclicklistener

Tags: android, dialog, timepicker

No error so far but no dialog come out when i click the EditText1 .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static final int dialog_id = 0;
int hour,minutes;
Button date;
Button time;
DatePicker dp;
TimePicker tp;
EditText et;
EditText et1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    et.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            date();

        }
    });

    et1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, mTimeSetListener, hour, minutes, false);
        }
    });

}  


public void date(){
    dp = new DatePicker(this);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Set Date")
    .setView(dp)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dp.getMonth()+1+"-"+dp.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+dp.getYear(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            et.setText(dp.getMonth()+1+"-"+dp.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+dp.getYear());
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    })
    .show();

}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                hour = hourOfDay;
                minutes = minute;
                String tme = hour +":"+tp.getCurrentMinute();
                et1.setText(tme);
            }
        };
```

This is a date and time picker dialog. The Datepicker works but the timepicker did not. I didn't do the same thing with the date picker because I cannot change the format of the time.

Comment: use a DialogFragment for the pickers. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01); is this id correct

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method after `et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);`

```
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minutes=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

And write `true` instead of `false` in the follwing line.

```
new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, mTimeSetListener, hour, minutes, false).show();
```

`true` for 24-hour format.

And replace follwing lines

```
        String tme = hour +":"+tp.getCurrentMinute();
        et1.setText(tme);
```

with        `et1.setText(hour+" : "+minutes);`

Hope its work.

Comment: @user3032164 your welcome. i think if you try this code there is no need to convert 24-hour format to 12-hour format explicitly. r u try this code?